# When testing a contract, NodeJS returns: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

Tags: solidity, web3js, nodejs, mocha

My NodeJS script gives me this error:

```
1)"before each" hook for "deploy a factory and a lottery"
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse((anonymous))
at Context.(anonymous) (test/lottery/test.js:18:46)
at processTicksAndRejections(internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
```

**File test.js**

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const compiledFactory = require('../ethereum/build/LotteriaFactory.json');
const compiledLotteria = require('../ethereum/build/Lotteria.json');
//two istances of the contract inside the build dir

let accounts;
let factory;
let lotteriaAddress;
let lotteria;

beforeEach(async () => {
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  factory = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface))
  .deploy({ data: compiledFactory.bytecode })
  .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });

  await factory.methods.createNew('5').send({
    from: accounts[0], //manager
    gas: '1000000'
  });

  const addresses = await factory.methods.active().call();
  lotteriaAddress = addresses[0]; //[LotteriaFactory]

   lotteria = new web3.eth.Contract(
     JSON.parse(compiledLotteria.interface),
     lotteriaAddress
   );
});

describe('Lottery', () => {
  it('deploy a factory and a lottery', () => {
    assert.ok(factory.options.address);
    assert.ok(lotteria.options.address);
  });
});
```

My dependencies are:

- solc 0.5.0
- web3 1.2.6

Can someone help me? What I am missing?

Comment: That's not an "npm error", but a NodeJS error (more specifically, an error from the Mocha testing framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the attempt to `JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface)`.

Function `JSON.parse` expects an input string which represents a valid JSON object.

You're attempting to obtain that object by **requiring** a JSON file:

```
const compiledFactory = require('../ethereum/build/LotteriaFactory.json');
```

But `require` statements are designated for importing JS code, not JSON objects!

Instead of requiring this file, you should simply read it:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const compiledFactory = fs.readFileSync('../ethereum/build/LotteriaFactory.json', {encoding: "utf8"});
```

Finally, in order to access the `interface` field of that object, change this:

```
JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface)
```

To this:

```
JSON.parse(compiledFactory).interface
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it was really helpfull to undersrand how JSON.parse works! Now i'm facing an other problem, I've changed the code but npm returns

 ("Error: you must provide the json interface of the contract when initiating a contract object"

My code right now is:

factory = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory).interface)
  .deploy({ data: (compiledFactory).bytecode })
  .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });

And the compiled object is: 

const compiledFactory = fs.readFileSync('./ethereum/build/LotteriaFactory.json', 'utf8');

Comment: @Gianna: Please post it as a separate question (and don't forget to accept this answer by clicking on the V next to it (if it answers your question of course)).